# Экспорт из DLL класса с шаблонными членами

Tags: c++, dll

Какое-то время назад, когда я пытался писать свою библиотеку-рендерер, выяснилось, что если в экспортируемом из DLL классе есть члены, которые являются объектами некоего шаблонного класса (например, std::vector), то их нужно явно экспортировать для конкретного типа.

Экспортируемый/импортируемый класс с шаблонным членом:

```
class ENGINE_API SampleClass
{
private:
    std::vector<float> m_cSomeArray;

public:
    explicit SampleClass();
    ~SampleClass() = default;
    [[maybe_unused]] std::vector<float> foo();
    [[maybe_unused]] std::vector<float>& foo2();
};
```

Отдельно экспортируемый/импортируемый шаблонный класс члена:

```
template class ENGINE_API std::vector<float>;
```

Затем выяснилось, что подобный экспорт классов из стандартной библиотеки - плохая практика, поскольку стандартная библиотека у компилятора собирающего клиентское приложение может отличаться от той, что была у компилятора собирающего .dll

Насколько я понял, существуют 2 пути, как эту ситуацию можно разрулить:

- Использовать чистый C-интерфейс при экспорте из .dll, и экспортировать только функции (плюс - dll можно использовать везде, минус - нет ООП, нет возможности пробрасывать исключения)
- Написать свою собственную библиотеку вспомогательных шаблонных контейнеров, которая гарантированно будет одной и той же для dll и для клиентских приложений.

И на этот раз я решил пойти вторым путём, но возникли вопросы:

1. Если это шаблонный класс, описанный в заголовках, которые используются и в dll и в клиентском приложении, то нужно ли мне **импортировать** такие классы в клиентском приложении, если я их экспортирую в .dll? То есть, правильным будет делать вот так:

   ```
    template class ENGINE_API types::Vector<float>;
   ```

   Или вовсе вот так:

   ```
    #ifdef ENGINE_EXPORTS
    template class __declspec(dllexport) types::Vector<float>;
    #endif
   ```

   Как бы я не делал, всё работает, и компилятор не ругается, но я не до конца понимаю.. Допустим, я импортирую `Vector<float>` на стороне клиентского приложения, значит ли это, что если я буду теперь просто создавать объекты такого типа на стороне клиента, это будет уже `Vector<float>` из библиотеки, а не клиентский? Это хорошо или плохо? А если я НЕ импортирую, но функция `foo2()` вернет *ссылку* на такой объект, то.. насколько корректно я вообще смогу взаимодействовать с таким объектом?
2. Насколько вообще идея "сделать свои STL контейнеры во избежании проблем с экспортом" соответствует "хорошей практике"? Просто, как мне кажется, при взаимодействии с библиотекой куда удобнее будет использовать какие-то ооп-враперы, а не голые указатели и сишные массивы (например, если захотим передать в качестве аргумента массив вершин). Как вообще подобное принято делать? Я заметил что разработчики игровых движков любят переписывать STL, но до конца не понимаю с какой целью это делается.

Comment: *"стандартная библиотека у компилятора собирающего клиентское приложение может отличаться от той, что была у компилятора собирающего .dll"* - они не должны отличаться, жесткая привязка к версии компилятора и релевантным параметрам сборки должна быть реализована на уровне С++ интерфейса библиотеки. А если есть потребность обеспечить бинарную совместимость, то следует делать С интерфейс.

Comment: @user7860670 Понятно, что собирать как клиентское приложение, так и саму библиотеку необходимо с использованием одного и того же компилятора с одинаковыми параметрами сборки.. Тут речь скорее о том, что может возникнуть ситуация, когда я буду писать свою библиотеку исходя из того что в STL есть определенные классы работающие определенным образом, а кто-то другой соберет всё в такой среде, где STL будет чуть другим, и будут работать чуть иначе (или вовсе что-то будет отсутствовать). Возможно эту проблему призваны решать свои контейнеры.. но может и нет.

Comment: STL - часть стандарта языка. Вопросы касающиеся производительности и организации хранения данных (например, что vector.data лежит в памяти одним куском) закреплены в стандарте - нужно найти очень - очень - очень нестанлартный компилятор, чтобы что-то сломать.

Comment: Хм, а если изначально все собирается под 17 стандарт, а потом кто-то решит собрать под 20-ый, где что-то уже изменилось? И если в этом плане нет никакой опасности, то зачем разработчики игровых движков переписывают STL и делают свои контейнеры? Но даже если можно просто использовать STL - насколько хорошо и правильно экспортировать эти классы? Я правильно понимаю, что если клиентское приложение импортирует " template class ENGINE_API std::vector<float>", то использование vector<float> уже будет не тем же самым что без импорта?

Comment: *"а если изначально все собирается под 17 стандарт, а потом кто-то решит собрать под 20-ый, где что-то уже изменилось"* - а это будут уже его проблемы, а не ваши. А чтобы это не выливалось в какие-то рандомные непонятные последствия, то следует делать жесткую привязку к версии компилятора и релевантным параметрам сборки. Т.е. чтобы этот кто-то получил осмысленную ошибку в случае несоответствия сборки.

Comment: Нормально написать свой вектор - не так просто, как вы думаете (правильно обрабатывать исключания, поддержать кастомные аллокаторы...). Челлендж интересный, но на практике я бы самодельный вектор не применял.

Comment: В любом случае, буду ли я писать свой вектор (и прочие шаблонные контейнеры), или использовать STL - при экспорте классов, мне придется делать экспорт инстанциированных для необходимых мне типов шаблонных классов. Насколько это хорошо? Нужно ли импортировать такие классы на стороне клиента? Может быть, если такая необходимость возникает, это говорит о неправильной структуре проекта и делать движок/рендерер в виде отдельной .dll это не очень хорошо?

Answer (score 2):

**Пыльная быль**

Относительно того, почему некоторые игроделы не используют STL - один из примеров, это id Tech 4, то есть движок Doom III. id там сознательно не используют ничего из STL и [объясняют это тем](https://kotaku.com/the-exceptional-beauty-of-doom-3s-source-code-5975610), что код на выходе получается интуитивно непонятным, плохо выглядит и работает медленно.

Сделаем большое замечание - разработка Doom III началась в 2000 году, через два года после появления C++98, который кое-как закрепил `STL` как часть языка `C++`, и то со скрипом (Окончательно - только в 2003 году).

Отсюда следует, в частости, что 22 года назад, действительно, можно было наткнуться на ряд проблем:

1. Просто багнутая `STL` / компилятор (Borland С++ Builder в качестве примера)
2. Плохо работающий оптимизатор, вырабатывающий медленный код.  В целом, успешность оптимизации кода с STL - это [стресс-тест](https://rsdn.org/article/devtools/CppPerformance.xml#EUF) (Имени Степанова, который S в первоначальном названии STL) для компилятора.
3. Медленно работающий компилятор - как по причине тормознутости самого компилятора, так и по причине ресурсов олдскульного железа.
4. [Недостаток / недоступность документации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0), поясняющей, что там творится под капотом. (Например, технология обработки исключений просто не была стандартизирована).

Понятно, что для целей коммерческого игростроя при таком количестве проблем, проще использовать свой код, нежели погружаться в пучину работы в условиях множества неизвестных.

**Современность**

Отмечу, что сейчас на дворе 2022 год. За 22 года произошло следующее:

1. Популярные компиляторы прекрасно справляются со сборкой кода, применяющего `STL`, достойно его оптимизируют и не вносят баги (как правило).
2. Есть огромное количество ресурсов, начиная от самого стандарта языка, который доступен в виде черновиков на гитхабе, ресурсов типа `cppreference.com` и книг-учебников, где написано, какие гарантии обязана предоставлять пользователю `STL`.
3. Вышла `11я`, а потом `14я`, а потом и `17я` и `20я` версии стандарта, которые на порядок понизили страшность кода, написанного с применением STL, а также закрепили многие неясности насчет деталей реализации контейнеров - например, что `std::string` обязана храниться одним куском, так же как и вектор.
4. Так как знание STL/Boost является обязательным требованием практически в каждом объявлении о вакансии, гораздо больше программистов понимают код на `STL` (и удивляются, видя велосипед).

**К заключению**

Выбор той или иной технологии является прерогативной разработчика. В данном случае, разработка собственного решения означает затраты времени на написание и тестирование, зато дает команде, теоретически, чуть больше контроля над происходящим.

Это было актуально 22 года назад, когда `STL` только появилась и ее поддержка как со стороны компиляторов, так и со стороны документации была посредственной, но в данный момент, эти проблемы в большинстве своем устранены, что делает разработку собственного варианта стандартной библиотеки малорентабельным предприятием - в крайнем случае, можно поискать реализацию контейнеров с нужными свойствами в опенсорсе.

**Важное**

При индивидуальной разработке just for fun, для получения опыта и развленчения, вся моя трескотня о рентабельности и продуктивности теряет смысл, потому что я не считаю корректным указывать человеку, каким конкретно способом развлекаться с помощью программирования.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Понял, использовать STL все же лучше чем велосипед (хотя почему в том же QT до сих пор думают иначе, с учетом развития стандартов языка, все же интересно). Но вопрос с экспортом шаблонов все еще остается открытым. Допустим, буду я использовать STL, что делать с шаблонными членами экспортируемых из DLL классов?

Comment: Так за Qt тянется след еще более длинный, чем за id tech (начало разработки - 1991 год). Кроме того, имеется обратная совместимость с 4 по 6 версию, а со скрипом и бубеном - на третью. Вот и таскают они за собой тележку с легаси.

Особенно изящные пляски с бубеном начинаются при попытке объединить чисто STL-библиотеку c Qt - к коде появляются разного рода переходники и адаптеры для перекладывания байтиков с места на место.

Answer (score 1):

Относительно экпорта шаблонов - давайте смотреть на коллег по цеху - именно, на библиотеки `Boost` и `Eigen` (На мой взгляд, `Eigen` является эталоном того,  как должна выглядить библиотека линейной алгебры на `C++`). Их шаблонные части распространяются в исходниках, что дает компилятору широкие возможности для инлайна и оптимизации (которых просто не будет, если код упрятан в `dll`).

Например, есть у вас тривиальный геттер (`float getX() const {return x;}`). Его тело находится в `dll`. Следовательно, вместо того, чтобы просто взять `float` по адресу "база класса + смещение поля", процессор отправляется в путешествия в недра библиотеки.

Теперь, пусть наш клиентский код делает `foo.getX() + foo.getY() + foo.getZ()` (Кто-то заходел посчитать Манхэттенское расстояние). В условиях, когда текст метода `get...()` компилятору доступен (то есть, предоставлен ему в виде шаблона), он увидит, что речь идет о сложении трех `float` которые лежат в памяти подряд, и можно использовать векторную инструкцию, получив ускорение примерно в 2-4 раза.

Если же код метода `get()` лежит в `dll` - оптимизацию выполнить невозможно, нужно обязательно делать 3 отдельных вызова `get()`.

**Делаем вывод**, что раз речь зашла о шаблонах, их выгоднее давать в виде исходников, иначе под сомнение попадает сам факт их использования - мы усложнили код, напихав в него шаблоны, но выгоду в виде оптимизации по месту мы упустили.

Comment: Вопрос был скорее не об экспорте шаблонов, а об экспорте классов (из DLL) которые используют шаблоные типы (при объявлении членов, или при возвращении значений у методов). Сами по себе шаблоны я держу исключительно в хедерах, но классы моей DLL, которые я экспортирую, используют эти шаблоны. Эти же шаблоны использует и клиентское приложение (которое использует и эту DLL, которая может возвращать такие объекты или ссылки на такие объекты). Это все в целях удобства (чтобы можно было общаться с API библиотеки при помощи STL/GLM/своей либы). Но это поражадает проблемы (о которых я писал в вопросе)

Comment: Так вам же написали, что нужно собирать все гарантированно одним компилятором с идентичными настройками и вы с этим согласились. STL тоже жестко зафиксирована стандартом, и вероятность того, что что-то изменится в новом C++ до такой степени, что потеряется обратная совместимость с STL является очень малой величиной (представьте себе, сколько кода отвалится)

Comment: Ок, всё будет собираться одним и тем же компилятором, с теми же настройками компиляции, но если я НЕ экспортирую интанциирвоанные для конкретных типов шаболоны (template class ENGINE_API types::Vector<float>), компилятор пишет варнинг при экспорте API-шного класса. Если экспортирую - не пишет. Но при этом, как вы и сказали выше, тогда получается двойная работа со стороны клиентского приложения. Но я ведь могу экспортировать на стороне DLL но НЕ ИМПОРТИРОВАТЬ на стороне клиентского приложения. Варнингов от компилятора нет, и двойной работы при обращении к функциям нет, но разве так можно?

Comment: Покажите текст WARNING

Comment: "doka::types::Vector<float>" должен иметь dll-интерфейс для использования клиентами class "doka::engine::SampleClass". Если использовать STL будет то же самое. Экспорт устраняет этот варнинг, импорт никак не влияет на варнинг.

Comment: Это ваш перевод, или у вас студия на русском языке? А какой код у Warning?

Comment: Компилятор студии, я так понимаю, берез зяык из настроек системы. warning C4251: doka::engine::SampleClass::m_cSomeArray: class "doka::types::Vector<float>" должен иметь dll-интерфейс для использования клиентами class "doka::engine::SampleClass"

Comment: Изучайте: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132747/warning-c4251-when-building-a-dll-that-exports-a-class-containing-an-atlcstrin